# where does Airflow 1.10.1 store logs for it's three services namely webserver, scheduler and worker

Tags: celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

We recently upgraded to Airflow 1.10.1 from 1.8 and we observed that Airflow services are no more writing logs in /var/log/airflow

we are using custom commands to run airflow services and even those commands don't write to the log files specified in the commands:-

nohup airflow scheduler -sd /usr/airflow/DAGS --stdout /dev/null --stderr scheduler_error.log > /dev/null 2>nohup_error.log &

nohup airflow webserver -p 8080 --stdout /dev/null --stderr /usr/airflow/airflow_webserver_error.log --error_logfile - > /dev/null 2>/usr/airflow/nohup_airflow_webserver.log &

scheduler_error.log and airflow_webserver_error.log files remain empty.

Is the service logging mechanism broken in airflow?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Check the `airflow.cfg` for `base_log_folder` location, where the logs should be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: this isn't really an answer, rather just an account of my limited experience with `Airflow`*

---

Recently I've also been tormented by the mystery around logging in `Airflow` (`v1.10.2`). Based on my usage experience (`LocalExecutor`), here's what I know (**please correct me if I'm wrong**)

- **Webserver logs**: I never found any directory / file explicitly titled *"webserver_logs"* (or something similar). Of course you get something on (`Linux`) *shell* when you invoke `airflow webserver` command. However since parsing of `DAG` is presently done by `webserver` *process* (checkout [this](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/2575131a6bfd877bf9b43c783bdc65a085ecac705976d3d8a7c73647@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E) thread and [AIP-12](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-12+Persist+DAG+into+DB)), those logs can be found at `base_log_folder/scheduler/date/path/to/your_file.py.log` (surprise, it is in `"scheduler"` folder). As already pointed out by **@Chirrut Imwe** `base_log_folder` [points to](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L43) `AIRFLOW_HOME/logs` by default
- **Scheduler logs**: I'm unaware of their whereabouts except for the lines I see on shell when I launch it using `airflow scheduler` command
- **Task logs**: These are located at `base_log_folder/dag_id/task_id/date_time/1.log`. Of course you directly see them [on the WebUI](https://airflow.apache.org/ui.html#task-instance-context-menu) using `View Log` button (after clicking on you `task`'s *bubble*)
- **Worker logs**: Since I'm on `LocalExecutor`, so never came across this. But you could try to get hints from [`puckel/docker-airflow`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) where they have provision for `CeleryExecutor` too

---

The [`UPDATING.md`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/UPDATING.md) page has a substantial amount of stuff on logging

Answer (score -1):

have you checked $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/ ?